# How to make a primary key with 2 columns being secure without autoincrement?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, auto-increment, identity

I have a table named `[Purpose]` and another one named `[PurposeMoviment]`.

Each Time a Purpose is edited `(values​​, products, services, deadline, etc.)`, the PurposeMoviment will be generated.

Can I have PurposeMoviment with 2 pk columns (`Purpose_ID, PurposeMoviment_ID`) where PurposeMoviment is manually created by my system?

When I say manually created, is a simple GetLastPurposeMoviment + 1. 
Its safe?

I'm asking because I want to show the actual number of moviments, like 1, 2, 3 ... Using identity, the moviment number will be 1 ... 4 ... 193.

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I'm new to big environments and afraid about many peoples press the button to insert purpose at same time and make my manual-increment fails.

I'm using MVC5, Entity Framework 6 and Repository Pattern.

Thanks guys

Comment: If you want an increment to be conditional to another value, basically a sequence number - you'll have to control that logic yourself. Identity will count up regardless of the group plus can provide you with holes in the sequence. So you'll need to count it yourself before inset or using an specific trigger logic.

Comment: I'm new to big environemnts, so I'm afraid about two or more peoples press the insert button and my simple control (getlast+1) fails or something else.
Do you have any kind of tips? I'm using RepositoryPattern in a Website (mvc5 + entity framework 6).
I'm trying to avoid triggers too.
Thanks

Comment: If possible, just keep the identity column and then just use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Purpose_ID ORDER BY Identity_Column) as PurposeMoviment_ID` when `SELECT`ing from this table to generate your sequential, without gaps, values.